# Installing ubuntu on a blank drive

Tags: boot

I was given a lenovo b350 with a bad drive. I have a blank hd. I also have a mac mini circa 2012 with dual drives.

Not sure if i can format it into something ubuntu can use to boot with, so. . .

Sorry if i've missed where this info is, but i've posed the question 6 different ways and can't seem to figure out how to make a bootable image on the drive.

thanks

Comment: Is your intention to use one of the mac's drives in the lenovo? Is the bad drive the blank hd? The information provided is somewhat confusing

Comment: Sorry.  I read it three times.  I'll try to say it differently.  I was give a computer with a bad drive. Out with it.  I have a BLANK HD.  Now i know i can't stick a blank HD in a machine and do anything, i need a bootable drive.   

In my possession is a mac-mini with dual drive, etc.  I only mention that because it is my experience you need to let people know what tools you have.

Lenovo is a windows machine.  With no windows on it currently, i'd like to install Ubuntu on the Lenovo, on the blank non formatted drive.

Thank you for your consideration.

Comment: Yes of course you can't boot to the blank HD, but most newer machines provide a method to boot from DVD or USB.  You will need to make a bootable medium using your MAC - first you need to download the ISO from http://releases.ubuntu.com/16.04/ . You'll have to choose the ISO for the lenovo 64 bit amd. Follow instruction >http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/burn-a-dvd-on-mac-osx. Insert the just burned DVD into the Lenovo and turn it on.

Comment: thank you, let you know.  I'm assuming then, that i can just shove the unformatted hd into the win machine, insert the dvd, and turn it on. Burning DVD now.

Comment: No go. Lenovo shows Error 1962: no operating system found. Boot sequence will automatically repeat.

Comment: did the computer access the dvd at all?

Comment: here's link to the user manual if you didn'y get one ... www.lenovo.com/shop/americas/content/user_guides/b350_ug_en.pdf    read page 37 concerning uefi and legacy

Comment: It did not access the dvd.  Thanks for link, that was the first thing i got.

Comment: I suggest attempting the legacy in bios and try booting again

Comment: We tried for several hours last night, no problem getting into the bios, no problem switching just about ever configuration.  No go. Also tried the 32 bit, still no go.  I've now gone to USB drives to install, and it sees the drive, if the light on the drive is any indication, but still get the 1962 error code. Lots and lots of reading, and watching you tube.  Will try again tonight, let you folks know.  Thanks for any help or ideas, I will not be defeated. Donated to Ubuntu.  thanks community.

Answer (score 0):

Thats easy!

put the new HDD in the laptop

Download a Ubutnu image:
http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop

install it on a usb:
http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-mac-osx

If you can't boot from USB, make a CD. (usually not necessary.)

(Assuming you want to install Ubuntu, not Winblows)

Install Ubuntu the normal way. When it asks for partitions, make a big linux one (`EXT4`) and a small Swap space one. (Like 4gb or so.)

Comment: I tried that. Lenovo said no os. The hd i have is blank.  and yes, i only want to install Ubuntu. 

I made a DVD.  Nothing. I can remove the HD and format it to anything that Disc Utility in my mac will format it to.  

I understand that the Ubuntu image will then reformat it.  At any rate, without some sort of boot image/disk, it's not going to do anything, i wouldn't think.

Answer (score 0):

While i can not give a super detailed answer, it was in the bios. My friend and resident guru came over today and fixed it. It was indeed in the bios settings. We didn't have the boot from usb set properly.  I've asked him to update this so that the community will know if this comes up again.  Thanks to all that helped.  I'm super happy this worked, and am putting the computer out in my wood shop right now. It is fully networked with my mac mini, and the remote printer works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

The fix to the problem was in adjusting the boot mode and the boot order in the BIOS. Some of the instructions you will find on this device reference the "Novo" button to get to the BIOS setup and the Boot menu.  If you don't have the original keyboard you won't have a Novo button, but the BIOS is still accessible if you press F1 at power up and the Boo menu is accessible if you press F12 at power up.

As to the changes I made, I switched the device's boot mode from Automatic to Legacy Mode.  I don't know if that was strictly required, but I did it and it worked so there you go.  The other change I made was to adjust the boot order placing USB Key at the top of the list.  Some good instructions can be found in *Lenovo B350 Maintenance Manual* at http://www.manualslib.com/manual/577646/Lenovo-B350.html?page=22#manual

Curiously, the boot order change did not work the first time.  I redid it with an bootable Ubuntu install image on a USB Key inserted into a USB port. The USB Key appeared as in instance beneath, the "USB Key" entry.  I saved the new state, rebooted, pressed F12 several times on boot and the USB Key appeared in the boot menu. I was then able to start the Ubuntu installer.

The Ubuntu install itself was uneventful.  I used Ubuntu Desktop 16.04.1 and all the needed drivers loaded fine. So the problem was never about Ubuntu. It was just a persnickety BIOS and some misleading instructions for that BIOS.